# c printf(%*s) explanation

Tags: c, printf

So, I am trying to output a formatted string of mario's pyramid, i.e:

```
   ##
  ###
 ####
```

The dots represent spaces.  The height is determined by the user during runtime.  The following code is what I have found to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void hash(void) {
  printf("%s", "#");
}

int main(void) {
  int height;
  printf("%s", "Enter height of mario's pyramid: ";
  scanf("%i", &height);

  for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    int spaces;
    if (height == 1 || i == (height - 1) {
      spaces = 0;
    }
    else {
      spaces = height - (i + 1);
      printf("%*s", spaces, " ");
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < (i + 1); j++) {
      hash();
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Now that you see what works, let's see something that doesn't work, everything is the same except the for loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void hash(void) {
printf("%s", "#");
}

int main(void) {
  int height;
  printf("%s", "Enter height of mario's pyramid: ";
  scanf("%i", &height);

  for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    int spaces;

    spaces = height - (i + 1);
    printf("%*s", spaces, " ");

    for (int j = 0; j < (i + 1); j++) {
      hash();
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

So, as you can see, the only difference is the conditional statements, setting spaces to 0 if `height == 1` or `i == height - 1`, but the outcome is completely different.  For some reason, when using the conditional statements, the space doesn't seem to print, which is actually what I wanted, but I'm pretty sure this isn't how I should do it.  So, I was wondering if anyone knows what exactly is happening here and could explain it to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command:

```
printf("%*s", spaces, " ");
```

Will always print at least one space, because a single space is the string you're printing.

Change it to print an empty string:

```
printf("%*s", spaces, "");
```

Comment: Okay.  So, I guess I should be more specific.  Why is the first program working?  The spaces should still print, but they aren't?? Weird!

Comment: @TimBeyer They don't print in the first case because the call to `printf` is inside the `else` part, not the `if` part, so it's never called.

Comment: It is called and it does print the spaces, except when height == 1 and i == height -1.

Comment: In the first program, setting `spaces = 0;` is pointless because `spaces` is not used after that.

Comment: @TimBeyer Precisely, because in the `height == 1 || i == (height - 1)` part the `printf` function is not called.

Comment: Ha.  Sorry.  Exactly, its not being called in the if statement, thus its not printing the space. Thanks for working with me on that.

Comment: @TimBeyer Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

In the last iteration of the `for` loop the value of `spaces` is `0`, this is equivalent to

```
printf("%*s", 0, " ");
```

and `printf` prints a space even if the width specifier is `0`, change to:

```
if (spaces > 0)
    printf("%*s", spaces, " ");
```